# How to send an SMS with image to handphone?

Tags: sms

I'm using the service of a web site,and I can send text message using their interface(in PHP),but when I try to send an image :

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo27.png" />
```

I'm receiving exactly the same code,not an image.

Anyone has experience with SMS services?

Comment: And since when can txt messages contain images? Or are you talking about a multimedia message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Short Messages" are intended for plain text and losing money to Telcos. If you want do to anything with multimedia (like sending images), use EMS (Enhanced Message Service) or MMS (Multimedia Messaging Service). If you want to embed stuff from the web, use e-mail - the person who receives your message has to load the image from the internet anyway, and it's free for you if you send it from a computer.